# How to select a substring but leaving out the last character if is an alphabet in SQL

Tags: sql, substring, charindex

```
DECLARE @CUSTOMER_ID VARCHAR(50)
SELECT @CUSTOMER_ID = 'RS/123/2017(SA)' 
PRINT @CUSTOMER_ID

DECLARE @CUSTOMER_ID1 VARCHAR(50)
SELECT @CUSTOMER_ID1 = 'RS/123/2017SA' 
PRINT @CUSTOMER_ID1
```

I need a function that can return my customer_ID except for the last characters in the string. I can only work on the first one using the below function.

```
case when charindex('(',@CUSTOMER_ID) = 0 then @CUSTOMER_ID 
else left(@CUSTOMER_ID,charindex('(',@CUSTOMER_ID)-1))
```

Comment: Please post desire results in question.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  Multiple examples -- of both inputs and results -- would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a position of the rightmost digit and take left symbols of the string including this position

```
DECLARE @CUSTOMER_ID1 VARCHAR(50);
SELECT @CUSTOMER_ID1 = 'RS/123/2017SA';

select left(@CUSTOMER_ID1, len(@CUSTOMER_ID1) - patindex('%[0-9]%', reverse(trim(@CUSTOMER_ID1))) + 1) customer_ID;
```

Comment: What will be the opposite to this? suppose i want to return  'SA' from string 'RS/123/2017(SA)', even when is inside parenthesis i want only SA.

Comment: `right (@CUSTOMER_ID1 , patindex('%[0-9]%', reverse(trim(@CUSTOMER_ID1))) +1, 8000)` will return the right part. Then apply `replace` twice to delete '(' and ')'

Answer (score 0):

you can use substring like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(@CUSTOMER_ID, 0, LENGTH(@CUSTOMER_ID) - 1) FROM your_table
```